# How to disable ehcache using an external property in spring

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I need a quick help from you to fix a small problem.

In one of my project (using spring as core container), i am using ehcache to cache data. I am using spring ehcache annotations project (http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/) for the same.

I want to have flexibility to enable and disable ehcache based on a external property. I read ehcache documentation and found that it reads system property net.sf.ehcache.disabled internally and if it set to true cache will be disabled and they recommend to pass this as `-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true` in the command line

I wanted to control it through externalized spring property file.

Then i thought of setting this system property in my spring application context file using MethodInvokingFactoryBean based on a externalized property.

Here is the code

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System"/>
            <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperties"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.disabled">"${ehcache.disabled}"</prop>
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Obviously `ehcache.disabled` is controlled via my externalized property file.

Plumbing works great but i guess order is not coming into place. By the time Application context is setting system property, cache is initialized and when cache was being initialized there was no property `net.sf.ehcache.disabled`, hence cache is not getting disabled. When i run application in debug mode and try to get `System.getProperty("net.sf.ehcache.disabled")` after application context is initialized, it is giving me the right value. (I tried both true and false).

One more thing i want to mentioned i am using spring wrapper to initialize my cache.

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven self-populating-cache-scope="method"/>

<ehcache:config cache-manager="cacheManager">
    <ehcache:evict-expired-elements interval="20"/>
</ehcache:config>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
      p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
```

I believe that disabling cache can not be that hard.

What is it that i am missing? Is there any easy way to do it in spring except command line?

Answer (score 2):

As of Spring 3.1 it is possible to use bean profiles which can read a property from a external property. You could wrap the declared bean inside a beans element:

```
<beans profile="cache-enabled"> 
  <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml"/> 
</beans>
```

And then activate that using an external property as mentioned in [this](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) blog post.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (pre-Spring 3.1) would be to add a bean id to your MethodInvokingFactoryBean declaration, then add a depends-on relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You can return `NoOpCacheManager` object if your external property is not true

```
    @Value("${cache.enabled}")
    private Boolean cacheEnabled;
```

```
    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {

        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();

        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration.setName("mycache");
        cacheConfiguration.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU");
        cacheConfiguration.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(1000);
        cacheConfiguration.setTimeToIdleSeconds(0);
        cacheConfiguration.setTimeToLiveSeconds(3600);
        cacheConfiguration.persistence(new PersistenceConfiguration().strategy(PersistenceConfiguration.Strategy.NONE));

        config.addCache(cacheConfiguration);
 cacheMaxEntriesLocalHeap, cacheEvictionPolicy);
        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);

    }
```

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        if(cacheEnabled) {
            log.info("Cache is enabled");
            return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
        }else{
            log.info("Cache is disabled");
            return new NoOpCacheManager();
        }
    }
```